# Shifted polygons using RasterToPolygon

Tags: arcpy, polygon-creation, numpy

I have a grid of cells with certain values (e.g. let's say from 1 to 6). I tried to create polygons associated to values above 4 with the help of arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster then arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion.

To do this, I used python to store the values and transformed every value > 4 to 255 (0 otherwise) so that the raster create becomes white and black, and the polygons created are based only on the 255 values.

My problem is that the polygons created are "shifted" from the original grid cells:
[image]

I have no idea why I get this. The description of the grid, that I used to reconstruct the NumpyArray gave me correct values (e.g. lowerLeft point).

Any suggestion?

EDIT:
Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
env.extent = "MAXOF"
env.workspace = "C:/Project/ArcGIS/(grids)"
Coordsystem = "GEOGCS['GCS_ETRS_1989',DATUM['D_ETRS_1989',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',8183294.64,630550.669301,674150.669301,8145094.64]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]"
arcpy.env.outCoordinateSystem = Coordsystem
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Extraction of data from the grid
gridCells = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("C:/Project/ArcGIS/(grids)/gridN1.dbf",["Data"])
gridCells_list = []
for row in gridCells:
    gridCells_list.append(row[0])

# Modification of data in a new list
gridCells_newList = []
for i in range(len(gridCells_list)):
    if gridCells_list[i] > 4:
        gridCells_newList.append(255)
    else:
        gridCells_newList.append(0)

# Grid description
pDesc = arcpy.Describe(gridN1)
pWidth = pDesc.extent.width
pHeight = pDesc.extent.height
lowerLeft = arcpy.Point(pDesc.extent.XMin,pDesc.extent.YMin)
gridCol = int(pWidth / 500)
gridRow = int(pHeight / 500)

# Array creation
gridArray = np.asarray(gridCells_newList).reshape(gridRow,gridCol)
gridArray = gridArray[::-1]

# Raster creation
gridRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(gridArray, lower_left_corner=lowerLeft, x_cell_size=500,y_cell_size=500,value_to_nodata=0)

# Execute RasterToPolygon
arcpy.RasterToPolygon_conversion(gridRaster, gridPolygons, "NO_SIMPLIFY", "VALUE")
```

Comment: Questions involving code should always include a code snippet as their starting point.

Comment: You should also give some informations about projection, as this often an issue

Comment: Looks like half cell offset. Is it lower left cell centre, or lower left corner of lower left cell?

Comment: Does this issue show in gridRaster if saved seperately?

Comment: This is lower left corner of lower left cell. I have the same problem with the raster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this happens quite often when you have not specified a snap raster for output to match with. For whatever reason when output is created it can, by default, simply try to create the raster in the space that makes sense for the cell size and total number of cells to be created.

As long as one of your inputs serves as a good model for your output to line up with (as in your screenshot) ... you can try adding these lines to your script to modify your "Environment" settings. I think this will fix the problem unless there are differences in projection between rasters (that would be my only other potential caveat). Even though your output is polygon there are temporary rasters involved in the process.

```
arcpy.env.snapRaster = "C:/data/snapraster"
arcpy.env.cellSize = "C:/data/snapraster"
```

or better yet ...

```
arcpy.env.snapRaster = gridRaster
arcpy.env.cellSize = gridRaster
```